# Drag & drop not working between Windows Explorer tabs in Windows 11 22H2

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, tabs, drag-and-drop

I just updated my laptop to Windows 11 22H2 and I installed all updates remaining. After all those updates, my File Explorer had enabled tabs. I tried to drag and drop between tabs and it didn't work. I tested the feature on my other computer and it works fine.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I did some search and I found nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide exact build numbers for each machine?

Comment: The build is the same on both machines: 22621.819

Comment: Same problem here : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-22h2-dragdrop-between-tabs-is-not/961b9a78-3307-457a-9396-15727bc0d48e?rtAction=1669819469269

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of submitting a tempoary comment

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 11 22H2 here and drag and drop between file explorer tabs is working. It is a bit picky and cut / paste works vastly better and more reliably.

That said, try two things:

**(1) DISM / SFC**

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(2) Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Everything.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.)

**(3)** If all the above does not resolve the issue, then you need to back up, check your back up, and reinstall Windows 11 fresh. (User Profile damage and / or more serious operating system damage).

Comment: The commands did not help. The Windows 11 Repair Install is a bit too agressive for a problem like that...

Comment: Repair Install is simple. Download it (some time), run it (about an hour), watch paint dry, and you come back to where you were. Not aggressive at all. I have done it numerous times. Since DISM did not help, Repair Install is now necessary. Let us hope Keep Everything works. as the step beyond is reinstalling Windows.

Comment: I did add a section 3 to my answer,